# What can I do to be able to use Getter and Setter meths with ArrayList

Tags: c#

I'd like to use getter and setter methods I wrote in my Nation class with `ArrayList`, but it doesn't work. `ArrayList` doesn't behave like an array.

The following code doesn't work:

list[i].getCapitol();

I found a way around it, but I need to use arrays.  I think the teacher wants me to only use `ArrayList`.

```
public string getCapitol()
{
    return capitol;
}
```

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean? Compilation error? Exception? Wrong result?

Comment: meths? is that really easier than writing methods? (factoring in the time taken to read this comment)

Comment: @musefan I don't understand the gist of your comm???

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is a non-generic collection, so the getter returns an `object`, not a strongly-typed `Nation`. Use `List<Nation>` instead, or cast the result of the getter:

```
string c = ((Nation)arrayList[i]).getCapitol();
```

Comment: I can't use List, because it's a homework. It doesn't work because ArrayList doesn't support it for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried casting the result you get out of the `ArrayList` getter? It's a very odd homework if you can't use the generic collections, as `ArrayList` is deprecated now. I would complain to your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the item to your type before accessing it's members, as `ArrayList` stores it's items as `object`.

On a side note: While it's nice to know about the `ArrayList` type (just in case you end up maintaining a C# 1.0 application), they are now obsolete and you should use the generic `List<T>` type instead.

Comment: How do you cast an object? Sorry, I am a complete newbie.

Comment: Arraylist list = (Nation) list?

Comment: Not quite. `Nation item = (Nation)list[i];` would be it.